# SQL Server Replication - FTP Snapshot: Policy requires SSL

Tags: sql-server, replication

1. SQL Server 2014 on both Publisher & Subscriber.
2. Publisher & Subscriber are across the internet.
3. Replication is Transactional Replication

Error messages:

> The process could not connect to FTP site '' using port 21. (Source:
>   MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20032)
>
> Get help:
>   http://help/MSSQL_REPL20032
>
> 220 Microsoft FTP Service
>
> 534 Policy requires SSL.
>
> (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL12003) Get
>   help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL12003

Is there a way around this without relaxing SSL policy for the FTP Server ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. You open the FTP site in IIS and change the SSL Settings from Require to Allow.

You have to check with the owners of the FTP site if this is allowed and I would recommend to use https if possible as this way you are transmitting the username and password using cleartext

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer - however, I mentioned that I don't want to relax the SSL policy when possible.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Then you have to use web replication, or script the ftp download and set up an alternative folder where you FTP the files to on the subscriber